# Android: Is swiping the app in recent screen cause the app to force close

Tags: android, notifications, forceclose

Does all the devices on android have the same behavior or are there any setting to stop having that behaviour.

On my device, the app will killed if swiped in recent app screen. In my senior's device, the app was not force stop when I look at the App Setting, the 'Force Stop' button still enabled.

Are there any configuration or in code to modify the behavior when swiping in recent app screen.

Comment: Swiping out from Recent will kill that particular Task for the App . A Single App can have multiple tasks . Take a Read [Recents Screen](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/recents) . And it should show same behavior on same OS versions..

Comment: The application running on senior's phone and mine are the same application i have implemented. If followed from the link you mention, our both phone should behave the same.

Comment: Whats a senior's phone ? You should mention add both device information with question . Also specify what is different behavior you are seeing ..

Comment: Can't remember what phone but he used Huawei and mine was samsung A9 lite with API 26. I assumed his one was later version. Behavior is simple. His one will not force close the application if swiped in recent app screen, but on my phone the app will be force close after swiped in recent app screen

Comment: I am experiencing this problem as well, I have two phone one is Samsung j4+ with Android 9 and one is Huawei Honor with Android 10. On the j4 phone when I swipe up my app from recent apps, the app process is cleared along with app state, and when I relaunch the app, app starts fresh. But on Android 10 phone swiping the app doesn't clear the app state, when I relaunch the app, it starts from the previous state.

Have you found the answer to this?

Comment: Any solutions found?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [difference between swipe kill the app and force stop related to Application class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72446773/difference-between-swipe-kill-the-app-and-force-stop-related-to-application-clas)